# Control multiple activity intents in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, deep-linking

I am trying to open my app depending on the url that is entered but in some cases it tries to execute several activities at the same time, is there any way to restrict this so that the MainAction does not execute when trying to execute another?, basically my manifest goes like this

**Main Activity**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
            <data android:host="www.test.com" />
            <data android:host="m.test.com" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="home"
            android:scheme="testapp" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Detail Activity**

```
<activity
    android:name=".DetailActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">        
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data
            android:host="detail"
            android:scheme="testapp" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:host="www.test.com" />
        <data android:host="m.test.com" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/homes"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

the problem is that when i try to open a link like "http://www.test.com/homes" this happens:
[image: multiple activities intent]

Answer (score 0):

Your DetailActivity should be declared as shown below, no intent filter is needed.

```
  <activity
    android:name=".DetailActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_detail"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">        

</activity>
```

Comment: but i want to trigger the detail when open the other url and the main activity only when try to navigate the homepage

Answer (score 0):

The thing that matters is the launchMode for the MainActivity

You should  read that : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: I have tried to put the main activity on standard and the detail activity on singletop but the result is always the same, it tries to open both activities when open the url in the original question